# Allow failure in Kubeflow Pipelines

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

**Context**

I have a `kubeflow` pipeline running multiple stages with python scripts. In one of the inner stages, I use `kfp.dsl.ParallelFor` to run 5-6 deep learning models, and in the next stage, I choose the best one with respect to a validation metric.

**Problem**

The issue is if one of the models fail, the whole pipeline fails. It'll complain that the dependencies of the next stage is not satisfied. However, if model A fails and model B is still running at that time, the pipeline state will continue to be running till the time model B is running, and it'll change only at end of all models in that stage.

**Question**

How can I allow partial failures in a stage? As long as at least one of the model is working, the next stage can work. How do I make it happen in `kubeflow`? For example, I have setup CI in Gitlab, which supports this.

If it is not possible to have this, I want the pipeline to fail immediately as soon as one model fails, and not wait for others only to fail later, which possibly can be way later based on configurations.

---

Obviously, a way to avoid failure will be to include a top level `try` - `except` in the python script, and it'll always return exit code as `0`. However, in this way there shall be no visual indication that one (or more) models failed. It can be recovered from the logs, but it's rarely monitored in a scheduled pipeline when the entire run status is successful.

Comment: I know about the existence of `ExitHandler`, but I am not sure whether it can be used to change status. Also, not sure if it's possible to use this on a specific set of operations, like only the parallel ones in my case, instead of applying globally.

Comment: It's not available right now. Here's the featre request: https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/7330